# Fading Canvas from Opacity 1 to 0 on Edges

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I am creating a Canvas with an image inside using

```
context.drawImage(image, (cWidth - iRatio)/2, 0, iRatio, cHeight);
```

And behind the canvas there is a Blue Wallpaper inside a Div.

[image: Canvas]

As you can see on the image (done on Photoshop), the Canvas (Image with the Sun) is fading from opacity 1 to 0.

How can I do it in Canvas with JS or CSS ? I want the Canvas edges(All, so Left, Right, Top and botoom) to have an opacity 0 and fading to center with opacity 1.

Comment: You can create a [radial gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createRadialGradient) in the center that fades from transparent to white (or whatever your background color is).

Comment: My background is an image, so I can't fade to a color, I need a Fade Effect from "visible Image" to "Not visible Image" (Like a Mask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask):

```css
img {
  mask:radial-gradient(circle, white 30%, transparent 60%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onn3y.png" />
```

MDN has many example - you can use gradients, svg, and even pngs to get the effect you want.

There's also [`mask-border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-border) but it isn't as well supported (for example, Firefox doesn't support it yet).

Comment: Thx for Help ! I'll Check that. Thought the best way was in JS with Canvas but if CSS does the job, it's good !

Answer (score 0):

### Using filter

Use `ctx.filter` to create a blur and use that blur to keep pixels you want and remove pixels from edge using `ctx.globalCompoiteOperation = "detination-in"`

Example below uses function `featherEdge` feather edges of canvas content.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const img = new Image;
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onn3y.png";
img.addEventListener("load", draw, {once: true});
function draw() {    
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    featherEdge(20, 2);
}

function featherEdge(blurRadius, inset) {
    ctx.filter = "blur(" + blurRadius + "px)";
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
    const inBy = blurRadius + inset;
    ctx.fillRect(inBy, inBy, canvas.width - inBy * 2, canvas.height - inBy * 2);
}
```

```css
canvas {
   background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```